# Transform list to dictionary with ID's and content

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Given list is `llist = ['4|right', ' 2|left', ' 2|down', ' 2|right']`

And the output must be like this:

```
outp = [
    {'id': 0, 'content': '4|right'},
    {'id': 1, 'content': '2|left'},
    {'id': 2, 'content': '2|down'},
    {'id': 3, 'content': '2|right'}
]
```

Comment: your output is not a dictionary but an (invalid) set of dictionaries, please ensure you're providing correct python

Comment: What is the key for access to each inner `dict`?! You can create as `list` of `dict`

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes of all the answers?

Comment: @kushcloud, you're welcome, I send here : `[{'id': idx, 'content':l.strip()} for idx, l in enumerate(llist)]`

Comment: @mozway Yes, you right. I was just writing it from my head and did a mistake. The answer is belowe. It has to be list of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided output is invalid (a set cannot hold dictionaries as those are not hashable), assuming you want a **list** of dictionaries:

```
outp = [{'id': i, 'content': s.strip()} for i, s in enumerate(llist)]
```

output:

```
[{'id': 0, 'content': '4|right'},
 {'id': 1, 'content': '2|left'},
 {'id': 2, 'content': '2|down'},
 {'id': 3, 'content': '2|right'}]
```